# Difference between + and CONCAT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    HomeAddress varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);

INSERT INTO Example VALUES ('Murphy', 'James','123 Easy St', 'New York');
INSERT INTO Example VALUES ('Black', 'John','345 Youfarted St', 'Boston');
INSERT INTO Example VALUES ('Black', 'Amy','123 Simple St', 'Chicago');
INSERT INTO Example VALUES ('Simpson', 'Bill','123 Whofarted St', 'New York');
INSERT INTO Example VALUES ('Jones', 'James','321 Foo St', 'Chicago');
INSERT INTO Example VALUES ('Black', 'John','275 Ipsum St', 'Boston');
INSERT INTO Example VALUES ('Murphy', 'Sean','983 Ifarted St', 'New York');
```

I have 2 different DBs, one of which is 2012, the other 2008. SO, I have to always deal with making code that works on both. I have a working 2012 query (using CONCAT()), but in 2008, trying to use the same query with '+' does not print anything.

This works:

```
DECLARE @sql2 NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT 
  @sql2 = CONCAT(@sql2, ', COUNT(CASE WHEN city = ''', City, ''' THEN 1 END) as ', QUOTENAME(City))
FROM
  Example
GROUP BY City

SET @sql2 = CONCAT('SELECT LastName', @sql2, ' FROM example GROUP BY LastName')

EXEC sp_executesql @sql2
```

Which produces this (which is what I want):

```
LastName    Boston  Chicago New York
Black            2        0        0
Jones            0        2        0
Murphy           0        0        2
Simpson          0        0        1
```

THIS, does not work:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT 
  @sql = @sql + ', COUNT(CASE WHEN city = ''' + City + ''' THEN 1 END) as ' + QUOTENAME(City) 
FROM
  Example
GROUP BY City

SET @sql = 'SELECT LastName' + @sql + ' FROM example GROUP BY LastName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

By 'does not work', I mean it does not print any results. All I get back is `Command(s) completed successfully.`

What gives???

OH! And please work within the confines of this query. I know there are other ways to skin this cat, but this is the way I have chosen. (I need it to be dynamic, and I need it to not use PIVOT.)

Comment: if you write out the @SQL before sp_execute@sql variable what does it show? and does that if you attempt to run it return results?

Comment: @xQbert - I dont know what you mean.

Comment: @WorkSmarter - Sorry, that was me grabbing at straws. Removing those does not do anything though.

Comment: @lukehawk  I'm saying show the value of sql variable so we can see the SQL it's trying.  and then, once we have that value, what happens if you try to run it yourself.  when troubleshooting I always get to the raw

Comment: Do I use 'print' to do that? 'print' produces nothing.

Comment: if print produces nothing then is one of the column values null? null + string is null right? where concat will treat null as empty string? So maybe coalesce the quotename and city fields? to empty string?

Comment: OOoohhhh.. Good Call!! Thanks! That might be what is happening. Is there a solution to that? Something that performs like CONCAT in 2008?

Comment: Your comments and @Kannan's answer made it correct!! Thanks!

Comment: `coalesce(field,'')` would convert null to empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

Reason: Without initialization by default it will be null, concat will handle null as empty string where as manual concatenation with + we need to handle null values.

Change your first line it will work

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = '' --Initialize with empty string

SELECT 
  @sql = @sql + ', COUNT(CASE WHEN city = ''' + City + ''' THEN 1 END) as ' + QUOTENAME(City) 
FROM
  Example
GROUP BY City

SET @sql = 'SELECT LastName' + @sql + ' FROM example GROUP BY LastName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks!! I also added a where clause to make it robust against NULL values that may be in the actual table (thanks to @xQbert).